# Getting a list of cases from a switch/case to use in a validation method

Tags: c#, factory-pattern

Long story short, I'm creating a factory that looks a bit like this:

```
    public static ITag GetByTagName(string tagName)
    {
        tagName = tagName.ToLower();
        switch (tagName)
        {
            case "devicevar":
                return new DeviceVar();
            case "devicefilter":
                return new DeviceFilter();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

But I also need a method that checks if `tagName` corresponds to an ITag. Essentially I'm checking to see if `GetByTagName` would return null without actually running it:

```
private List<string> tagNames = new List<string> { "devicevar", "devicefilter" };

public static bool IsValidTagName(string tagName)
{
    return tagName.Contains(tagName);
}
```

See how we have some ugly duplication there? I don't want to specify the possible values for `tagName` twice. I could always change my method so it uses the factory to try and instanciate an ITag and if it returns null, then I know it wasn't a valid value. But this just seems wasteful:

```
public static bool IsValidTagName(string tagName)
{
    return GetByTagName(tagName) != null;
}
```

There must be a better way

**NOTE:**

I have a good (albiet longwinded) reason for needed to make this check, and it's not

"Would GetByTagName return an ITag if I gave it this string? Yes? Okay, call GetByTagName"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create dictionary of type `Dictionary<string, Type>` which will map tag types to their names.

```
Dictionary<string, Type> tags = new Dictionary<string, Type>() {
    { "devicevar", typeof(DeviceVar) },
    { "devicefilter", typeof(DeviceFilter) }
};
```

Use `ContainsKey` to check if name is valid:

```
public static bool IsValidTagName(string tagName)
{
    return tags.ContainsKey(tagName);
}
```

Use Activator to create instances:

```
public static ITag GetByTagName(string tagName)
{
    tagName = tagName.ToLower();

    if (!IsValidTagName(tagName))
        throw new ArgumentException(); // or return null

    return (ITag)Activator.CreateInstance(tags[tagName]);
}
```

---

UPDATE (for performance) Instead of storing type in dictionary, store creation methods there:

```
var tagsFactory = new Dictionary<string, Func<ITag>>() {
    { "devicevar", _ => new DeviceVar() },
    { "devicefilter", _ => new DeviceFilter() }
};
```

And getting tags will look like:

```
return tagsFactory[tagName]();
```

Comment: Thanks for this and for going to the trouble of providing an example. I'd considered this approach but was worried about the performance of `Activator.CreateIntance()`, since it uses reflection and is typically about 20 times slower than `return new DeviceVar()` for example. In this case, performance is important as these methods will be getting hit a lot.

Comment: @IainFraser you can store `Func<ITag>` instead of type in dictionary. Each delegate will create appropriate `ITag` instance. E.g. `{ "devicevar", () => new DeviceVar() }`

Comment: Dude, that looks like an awesome answer! I will performance test that in the morning. But looks like just what I need!

Comment: @IainFraser I believe performance will be almost like simple constructor invocation in switch block

Comment: Okay, so I tested it. `Dictionary.ContainsKey` is comparable in performance to a simple invocation in switch/case and checking for null (about 1.1 times slower). The actual invocation when using `Dictionary<string, Func<ITag>` is between 1.9 to 2.5 times slower than iterating over switch/case (average is about 2.2).

Comment: But I love the elegance of your solution and the fact that it could allow third party developers to specify their own tags (which is actually a huge bonus on this project). Although the factory will be hit a lot, it'll still be hit around 2 orders of magnitude less often than the method that actually calls it, so I'm actually okay with trading performance for flexibility here. Thanks for a great solution! Answer accepted.

Comment: Anyway you always create another copy, you can simplify it like this `var tagsFactory = new Dictionary<string, ITag>() {
    { "devicevar", new DeviceVar() },
    { "devicefilter", new DeviceFilter() }
};` i mean using Func<T> is abolutly unnessesary instead of simple T

Answer (score 0):

if `tagName` always match TypeName, you can do not use any dictionary and write simply like this

```
    public static ITag GetByTagName(string tagName)
    {
        var type = typeof(ITag).Assembly.GetTypes().SingleOrDefault(t => string.Equals(t.Name, tagName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
        if (type == null)
            return null;
        return (ITag) Activator.CreateInstance(type);
    }

    public static bool IsValidTagName(string tagName)
    {
        return GetByTagName(tagName) != null;
    }
```

if your clases are not in the same Assembly you should fix a bit this code.

Advantage of this alternative is it works with any class in the assebmly and you don't need to enumerate them anywhere

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In this case I'm looking for performance, so using reflection is something I want to avoid. Also, there exist ITags that should not be available to `GetByTagName`.